# Mediawiki Search Text Within code blocks

Tags: mediawiki

I am using syntax highlight extension and also `<source>` tags in mediawiki for code blocks. Thats working fine. But, I cannot search for text within these code blocks? Is there any extension to fix it?

Problem: I cannot search "ifconfig" because it lives inside the code block

```
<source>
ifconfig
</source>
```

Any help?

I am using the following setup:

```
* Windows 7
MediaWiki - 1.19.2
PHP - 5.4.4 (apache2handler)
MySQL - 5.5.25a
Installed Extensions - SyntaxHighlight (Version 1.0.8.10)
```

Comment: Just by entering the search text in the textbox on the top right and hitting Search Button and then clicking on link "Everything"

Comment: You can't get such semantic searches. Use SemanticMediaWiki or spin-off all code excerpts to an own namespace and search that namespace.